# Ktor retry the request until certain condition met instead of fixed number of retires

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I would like to retry a request in ktor with exponential backoff when I get a 5XX response and its quite easy to do with the built-in plugin as shown below

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(HttpRequestRetry) {
        retryOnServerErrors(maxRetries = 6) // no I want to retry until non 5XX response
        exponentialDelay(maxDelayMs = 128.seconds.inWholeMilliseconds)
    }
}
```

But I would like to retry infinitely until I receive non 5XX error instead of only 6 times. Is there any straightforward way to achieve it? Currently, I do the trick by setting `Int.MAX_VALUE` to `maxRetries` as below

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
      install(HttpRequestRetry) {
          retryOnServerErrors(maxRetries = Int.MAX_VALUE)
          exponentialDelay(maxDelayMs = 128.seconds.inWholeMilliseconds)
      }
}
```

Of course, it's practically considered an infinite retry with a maximum interval of 128 seconds but I wonder if is there any other idiomatic function that exists to do the same without a trick.

Comment: According to the implementation, the plugin always compares the current retry count with the max retries, so there is no other way.